# powershell console & environment bootstrap (oh-my-zsh like?)

Tags: powershell

I'm setting up a new windows environment after being used to working in Linux & Mac. I want to use powershell, but it's hard to find a good bootstrap environment:

- console - which to use? I want textual, but would be nice if it supported graphic output (html?)
- history - search, persist
- git integration
- ssh support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check out ConEmu as a better console app.
- Not sure what you mean with the history thing, but there is a command history if you use the arrow up key in the console window. There's also on if you press F7.
- You'll need to install git for windows. There's also Posh-Git for more Powershell Git goodness. It has command line completion etc.
- SSH. Not sure. I think you can use PUTTY for that.

Unrelated but check out https://chocolatey.org to "apt-get" those onto your Windows box. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing a while back. I found a few things like Chris Benti's PsConfig to enable an agnoster theme in the Powershell console, but I still needed a more ZSH/Tmux like experience. So I created it .

I use ConEmu as the console to host my shells in. It has tabs/windows and a lot of configurable stuff (colors/fonts/...). PowerShell has a lot of things out of the box lately, tab completion, history, aliases, the likes. And it has quite a few cool libraries that mimick some of Unix awesome packages. I created oh-my-posh which has theming capabilities for PowerShell in ConEmu including git, error and elevated indications. It also has a few cool libraries for PS you might know from Unix (z, warp,...). Have a look on my blog for all the [information](https://herebedragons.io/oh-my-posh/).

For SSH, don't let anyone fool you. When you have git installed on Windows (which you do), add it's usr/bin folder to your path. It holds all the awesome Unix tools including ssh. This way you can use ssh just like you would on Unix, not having to deal with crappy GUI tools like Putty (because, really).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a90oXvQOwig

This should answer your question as it shows how to modify history output, install git integration and get colored prompt on PowerShell.